# Flex 3 ,ASP.NET and WCF

Tags: .net, asp.net, apache-flex, architecture

I want to create a web app. I want to use WCF for distributed transactions, ASP.NET at the middle, and because Flash is so popular, I want to write the front end with Flex3.

Does that sound like a good architecture to you ? are there any benefits including WCF ?

Can Flex interact nicely with ASP.NET ? or should I go Silverlight ?

Comment: yes, I mean WCF (Windows Communications Foundation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, I find the integration between WCF Services (using basicHTTPBinding) and Flex to be fantastic.  I've been using it for a year or so now, and have been really pleased with the results.

The benefits to using WCF, to the extent you can get your head around it (I chose Juval Lowy's look [Programming WCF Services](http://books.google.com/books?id=DW2ldput788C&printsec=frontcover&dq=Programming+WCF+Services&ei=423gSqvRAozskwSAq_2sCA#v=onepage&q=&f=false) to help me with that process, which I'd recommend if you aren't already familiar with it, since it's definitely got its own idiom), are numerous, but for me, it's mainly meant (a) not having to deal with serialization issues and (b) writing very little code.  Essentially, I define my types and the functions I want to expose as Web interfaces, and WCF takes care of the rest.  Flex's WebService class works splendidly with it.  You don't need any third-party software systems to handle connecting the two -- just spend a little time learning WCF, and you can do the work yourself.

It reminds me I should post an example on my blog showing just how simple it is to do this.  I'll post back with an update if I do.  Meantime feel free to post with comments if you have questions.  Best of luck!

Comment: Christian, thanks for your post.

is it a good idea to have these 3 parts ?

1) Flex
2) ASP.NET
3) WCF

Comment: Sure, you can (and often do) use both -- it depends on what you need. For example, I just completed a project for a client that uses ASP.NET Web forms to provide basic CMS functionality, and then as part of the CMS, there's a Flash component in one of the pages that handles a few tasks related to audio processing, and which hooks up to the database by way of a handful of WCF services.  Whether it's a good idea" depends on the nature of your project, but I can say it's a fine way to go, and I've had excellent experience with it personally.

Comment: Thanks Christian. I have three questions that I've been struggling with and seem to have a solution, but not sure it's the best solution (using WCF REST, ASP.NET MVC, Flex 4). (1) Are you specifying all your endpoints as POST so they can accept Authorization headers and adding a ?method=GET/PUT/etc to kludge a RESTful API? (2) And since using POST, do you include a params object with something in there, whether needed or not, in the HTTPService.send(params)? (3) Finally, are you using Stream in your WCF Method definition instead of data types (then converting Stream to NameValueCollection)?

Answer (score 0):

Look into a tool to handle communications between .NET and Flex, such as WebORB. You *can* use webservices, but it's faster to use the flash AMF format to move data to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Use either:

1. **WCF** - complext and very configurable
2. **Asp.net MVC** - simpler and very controllable/predictable

for server-side interface or Asp.net MVC that won't have any views.